# Verify $g(x) = \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)!(x-r)!}p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r}$ is a PMF

Tags: probability

Let $0<p<1$ and let $r$ be a nonnegative integer and let

$$g(x) = \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)!(x-r)!}p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r}$$

Where $x = r, r+1, .....$

Verify that $g$ is a probability mass function and derive the MGF of X where X is the random variable with PMF $g$.

So the trouble I am having here is that this almost looks like I can apply the Binomial Theorem. But here we have an infinite summation and we are summing with respect to the numerator of the Binomial Coefficient, which I have never seen before. I would like some help with knowing what I can do with the $x = r, r+1, .....$ and the strange Binomial Coefficient. Could we do something like summing with respect to $x-r = 0, 1, 2, .....$? Some guidance would be highly appreciated. I could most likely find the MGF once I know how to take the infinite sum of this function.

Comment: This is just the negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your MGF focus suggestion, let's prove$$\sum_{x\ge r}\frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)!(x-r)!}p^re^{tx}(1-p)^{x-r}=\left(\frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}\right)^r,$$or equivalently (with $k:=x-r$)$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{r+k-1}{k}p^re^{kt}(1-p)^k}=\left(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^t}\right)^r.$$(Technically this only works if $t<-\ln p$, but if that bothers any reader, they can mentally replace each expression of the form $e^{tu}$ with $e^{itu}$ so we're working with characteristic functions.)

Let $[y^\ell]f(y)$ denote the $y^\ell$ coefficient in $f(y)$, so with $z:=\frac{y}{e^t(1-p)}$ the blue sum is$$\sum_{k\ge0}[y^k](1-y)^{-r}p^re^{kt}(1-p)^k=\sum_{k\ge0}[z^k]\left(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^tz}\right)^r=\left(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^t}\right)^r,$$where we have used $\sum_{k\ge0}[z^k]f(z)=f(1)$ for a Maclaurin series $f$.